# Is there a way to prevent bitbucket pipeline to run more than once for the same commit?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

We have just set up scheduled pipelines in Bitbucket. We want them to be triggered to run as often as every hour, but only if there has been new commits to the branch. I can not find anywhere where this is described as possible or not. Does anyone here know a way to make this work?

Thanks in advance,
Lars